# ACUMATICA GENERIC INQUERY AND ATTRIBUTES

Tags: acumatica

I have 2 Attributes at the project header level and want to create a Generic Inquiry tied to the project that list all projects where Attribute 1 = a certain value while Attribute 2 = a different value.

For example getting a list of projects where Attribute1 = "Yes" but Attribute2 = "No"

Comment: Show what you have done till now.

Answer (score 0):

In the Generic Inquiry you must do two things before you lastly add the Project ID fields in the Results tab:

- Add and join the tables for project and attributes in the 1st two tabs.
- Add two conditions in Conditions tab for Attribute1, Attribute2.